# Cell Fracture Destruction

Tags: physics

I'm currently running into a weird issue with my scene and not sure how to overcome it. Firstly my cell fractured object with connections seems to be breaking before the ball hits it and when the ball hits the object not every connection is broken. Regardless of what threshold I use. Does anyone have any ideas?

Blend file:
https://pasteall.org/blend/a72bfbff307e424aacbc919d672b8026

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks,
Mitchell

Comment: Could you please include some screenshots in your post so we can tell at a glance what you're after and what's going wrong without having to dig through a blend file?

Comment: I've added the pictures to the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. delete all your constraints and your cells
2. select your original cube again, subdivide it 4 times then and hit F3 and restart cell fracture
3. use these settings (margin is important -> set to 0.01) and hit OK

[image]

4. before doing anything else hit M to move all created cells to a new collection - name it cells
5. on frame 25 keyframe "animated" for your sphere
6. on frame 26 uncheck animated and keyframe it
7. select one cell of your new collection
8. under physics properties hit rigid body
9. scroll all the way down and check "deactivated" and "start deactivated"
10. right click on your cells collection and choose "select objects"
11. then tap on object -> rigid body -> copy from active
12. start animation and it works

i made a quick video tutorial for you...but (!) this takes hours to upload, because my internet upload speed is slow as shit...so maybe in a couple of hours you can see it.
https://youtu.be/gizvc8fXhPY

[image]